# Gradle problem by implementing Braintree in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Good morning friends,

ok I edit the question. if I add the library

implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.3.0'

the following error occurs and the application does not compile,

Error: Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$1

add the library to try to eliminate the error : implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

but the error was greater

```
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "zeropodo.com.pagosbraintreeapp"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}




implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

//implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
```

My application does not compile.

Thank you very much for the help

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Comment: Which error message? Does it compile? What exactly is not working?